# DLL file creation using C++ in VS CODE

Tags: c++, dll

I will compile C++ code to create a DLL file using Visual Studio code. I adjusted all the settings according to the requirements, but whenever I tried to rebuild the project, I created a DLL file. I always get errors.

As I mentioned above, I tried to create a DLL file. I would appreciate it if someone gave me some suggestions on how I could solve this issue.

I encounter the following error:
`\*\ 1\>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\\Program Files\\Itasca\\ItascaSoftware900\\exe64\\plugins\\cmodel\\cmodelTUBSsalt_permd009.dll' 1\>Done building project "TUBSsalt_permd.vcxproj" -- FAILED. ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ========== ========== Rebuild started at 09:29 and took 03,775 seconds ==========\*\*`

Comment: That looks like visual studio output, not VS code. Common cause for this kind of issues is anti-virus software getting in the way,

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes,  it is Visual Studio code output, and I am trying to compile the project to create a dll file, but I always get this error.

Comment: _Visual Studio_ and _Visual Studio Code_ are two completely different applications.

Comment: The IDE you use is irrelevant. The compiler is clearly the one that comes with visual studio (or its commandline tools), not clang or gcc.

Comment: I am using Microsoft visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

This looks very suspect - `TUBSsalt_permd.vcxproj` probably builds `modelTUBSsalt_permd009.dll`, but why it it trying to do that in `C:\\Program Files` ?! That's not a location where you should be storing build output. Windows will not let ordinary programs write there, that's for installers to write to.

Comment: I use this dll file to run simulations in FLAC3D software, and that's why I chose the output directory in the VS code, so the file was created directly in the selected path.

Comment: We don't know if it's a permissions issue though. The file might be locked by an application currently using it.

Comment: @paddy: It's true that the file might _also_ be locked. But the permissions issue is still there. Visual Studio Code nor Visual Studio runs as admin

Comment: I adjusted the permission part also, but still got the same error.

Comment: It's not uncommon for people to grant themselves admin privileges without UAC, or even run as admin!! :( I think a good test would be for OP to try and manually delete that file from Windows Explorer and see what happens.